# Get error code when connecting to Postgres DB fail

Tags: java, postgresql, exception

I want to log the error codes when there are any problems with the PostGres DB, for example: 42703 for wrong column name, 08006 for connection failure. I've tried `getSQLState()` and it worked with the former case, but not the latter. Even I check the instance of the Exception before casting it to `SQLException` and call `getSQLState()`, I still get null value.

The two scenarios I have tried are stoping the Postgres service in Task Manager and using wrong username for connecting to the DB. Are there anything wrong with my method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connection failures are usually caught and handled by the database driver so those exceptions are consumed before your application can catch them. Generally to test if the database is available I use a select query and test for a non-null result, such as `SELECT 1;`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just wonder if they had specified the exact error code for each case, those codes must be used somewhere in the application other than just in the driver logging.

Comment: The codes are defined because the driver uses the same codes and catches them the same way your application would. Think of it this way... if one method of your application catches an exception, then any methods called later won't see that exception because it was already consumed. The database drivers are also Java methods, so they will catch the exception in their try blocks before your application has the chance to see it. So, to answer you, they ARE used somewhere in your application--by the driver, which is loaded into your code as a Java package from a jar (Java archive) file.

Comment: Got it! Thank you :)